# How to register a template in [NEW] WordPress site editor through a plugin

Tags: plugins, php, block-editor

I am trying to add a new template in the WordPress site editor like this [image: like this]

but unable to do it with my custom plugin.

I have found a filter to register a custom template

```php
add_filter( 'default_template_types', 'register_template_type' );

function register_template_type( $templates ) {
            $templates['help-us'] = array(
                'title'       => _x( 'Page: Help Us', 'Template Name' ),
                'description' => __( 'Displays Help Us template' ),
            );

            return $templates;
}
```

after adding this code I have figured out that by adding a file in the theme's template directory `help-us.html` I was able to register and display my custom template.

[image]

My question is how we can do this via plugin? Is there any way we can add a custom template via plugin folder? Like we can do in case of WooCommerce and other plugins. I am unable to find any hook for that.

Thanks

Regards

Syed Ali Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

Two of the best ways to do this are (1) by using **Create Block Theme** plugin or a (2) Child theme. Why complicate it with a new plugin?

In the child theme, create a `templates` folder, and in that, add a `custom-template.html` file.

You can also add a new template by using the Plus + button on top to add a new template and export it as either a new theme or as a child theme using **Create Block Theme**

[image: Create a New Template]

Comment: Maybe the OP wants their plugin's functionality include a template. Like copying the theme's page.php into a template that can be modified to include some functionality added by the plugin.  The process to have a plugin register a template is not well-documented.

Comment: Yes, as suggested by @RickHellewell I want to add this option in my existing plugin, I can not do this via child theme.